# Changing SharePoint Database and File location!

Tags: sharepoint-server, move, database-connection, database-server

I create a SharePoint 2013 environment with SQL 2012.  Issue is that SQL is installed on the OS driver (C drive). Now we want to move the location of SQL database and Log File from OS drive to Other local drive of the same Virtual Machine!!!
But we don't know if there would be any impact on SharePoint, of this movement !!

Does any body had done this before !! 
Need suggestions..

Answer (score 1):

Turn off the SharePoint server(s)

Detach the database from SQL using SSMS

Move the MDF(s)/LDF(s) to the desired location

Attach the database using SSMS, pointing it to the new MDF location

Start SharePoint